# Wpf WebBrowser load javascript

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have this `WebBrowser` in my page:

```
<WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="Browser"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Now after i load a page i want to inject a `JavaScript` code with :

```
var doc = (HTMLDocument)Browser.Document;
var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
var script = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
script.text = MYSCRIPTCODE;
head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)script);
```

And in `MYSCRIPTCODE` i have this function:

```
function checkSomething() {

    try{
           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           var url = 'weburl';
           xhr.open("GET", url, true);
           xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           //Somecode
           }

           xhr.send();
    } catch {

    }
}
```

And i run it with:

```
Browser.InvokeScript("checkSomething");
```

It's work perfect and run the script without any problem.

I have another state that i load local html file to the browser:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"OfflinePage.html");
Browser.Navigate(uri);
```

And when i want to run it with :

```
Browser.InvokeScript("checkSomething");
```

This line in the script get exception - Permission Denied:

```
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
```

Any idea why it happen? why it work in a page that i load from web and won't work in a local html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial page `OfflinePage.html` comes from the local file system, while your XHR URL is a web address. `WebBrowser` prohibits this as a cross-domain security restriction. You can use [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to solve the problem, but the web server should give explicit consent to cross-domain requests by including `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` HTTP header in response. More info on HTTP Access Control (CORS) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thanks man!! it's really because i load the file to the browser